# ListDensityPlot Animation in Mathematica

Tags: animation, wolfram-mathematica, density-plot

I have about 10 lists (declared as separate inputs), each of size 4x4, containing some values (densities), and I want to generate density plot animations (using the first list, then the second, and so on), similar to what we get by throwing in one of the lists into the ListDensityPlot function.

I couldn't find any straightforward way to do that. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `ListAnimate[ListDensityPlot/@lists]`?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It outputs the exact same line.

Comment: @vik Try exactly this in a new fresh notebook: list1=RandomReal[{-1,1}, {4,4}]; list2=RandomReal[{-1,1}, {4,4}]; list3=RandomReal[{-1,1}, {4,4}]; ListAnimate[ListDensityPlot /@ {list1, list2, list3}] and then see if you can adapt this to your actual data. Typo fixed.